How to create and present ListboxItems with partially italic text
Here i want to style listbox items in a way, that a little italic comment is added to some items, like shown in the image below.

What brought me close was using a List of Inline Items as a ItemsSource and add there some System.Windows.Documents.Run Objects. I face two challenges with this approach:

As of now i was not able to instantiate the Run object in a way to only style part of the text. So either it is all italic or bold or nothing. Its also a mystery how these types could possibly be combined.
Using List<Inline> as a ItemsSource overwrites the hover over and item select mechanism of the Listbox. It is not possible anymore to select an item with a single click and hovering over effect is just flickering.

How can i solve these two issues? Or does someboy know a better way?
Here is the small working example:
XAML
<Window x:Class="SandboxListbox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBoxWithColoredItems"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>

ViewModel
namespace SandboxListBox
{
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Run italic = new Run("Italic text") { FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic };
        Run reg2 = new Run("Another Regular Tet");
        Run reg = new Run("Regular Tet");
        Run fontfamily = new Run("Another font") { FontFamily  = new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS, Verdana") };
        Run big = new Run(" - big") { FontSize = 20 };
        Items =  new List<Inline> { reg, fontfamily,  reg2, italic };
    }
    private List<Inline> items;
    public List<Inline> Items
    {
        get => items;
        set
        {
            items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Inline selecteditem;
    public Inline SelectedItem
    {
        get => selecteditem;
        set
        {
            selecteditem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation left out
}}


By doing the formatting in the viewmodel you mix the view into the viewmodel. Instead the viewmodel should contain the logical separations and the formatting should be done in xaml.

Good point. But then my View needs to know when to style the comment. If one is present

Yes, you need some kind of structure of the Inline class. If Comment is null or empty you can choose not to show it.

You would do the text formatting in the ItemTemplate of the ListBox, like
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Comment, Mode=OneWay}" FontStyle="Italic"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

Use the above with a view model like this:
public class Item
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
}

For details see Data Templating Overview.

Excellent solution - thanks for that. This way the VM stays clear of styling
